# Creating display date function in php, OOP way

Tags: php

I am beginning to learn PHP OOP and I have this exercise to create a a function displaying a date.
I would like to come up with this result:
    $date = new ("14-01-2014"); // for example, this date from user

```
echo $date -> displaDate ('YYYY-MM-JJ'); // Would result to 2014-01-14
echo $date -> day; //Would result to 14
echo $date -> dayOfWeek; //Would result to Thursday
```

Can someone please explain to me how to start making a function for this?  I understand that functions has variables and methods.

Comment: Why not take a look at [DateTime objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and the [format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method

Comment: It seems that you don't clearly know what are the differences between functions, classes, objects and methods. I'd advice you to first learn some theory. Look up for some basic OOP tutorial.

Comment: @s3v3n I asked this question because I am trying to learn the theory and I also checked some tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're into implementing it yourself, you could go by doing it this way:

```
class Date
{
   private $KeysArray;

   // Members
   public $day;
   public $dayOfWeek;

   public function __constructor()
   {
      // 1) This should get the current date and save it in the "keys array":
      // the constants should of course be replaced with the method you're using to get 
      // the year, month or whatever.
      $this->KeysArray = array("YYYY" => YEAR_VALUE, "MM" = MONTH_VALUE...)
      // 2) Set all of the properties (data members):
      $this->day = DAY_VALUE
      $this->dayOfWeek = DAY_OF_WEEK_VALUE
   }

   public function DisplayDate($DateFormatString)
   {
       // 1) Parse the $DateFormatString. Turn it into an array of the terms. If it's      
       // always going to be split with "-", then you could use the function 
       // "explode()".
       // 2) Go over that array and try calling each item with the $this->KeysArray.
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply write a wrapper around DateTime?

Comment: This class is meant to wrap one of PHP's date, time or DateTime features. I thought he meant that he needs to implement this himself as homework.

Comment: You are right, Daniel. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

 $dt = new DateTime();
 echo $dt->format('j-n-Y');
 ?>
```

Comment: Please check This type.

Answer (score 0):

From version 5.2, PHP has `DateTime` class for the representation of date and time.

Eg.

```
$dateTime=new DateTime('NOW');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($dateTime);
echo "</pre>";
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

It's simple....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$t=time();
echo($t . "<br>");
echo(date('Y-m-d',$t));
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel Saad, thank you for helping me understand.  Here is the solution to my question:

```
class Date{

    private $dateString;    

    function __construct( $dateString )
    {
        $this->dateString = $dateString;    
    }


    // Method to display date in different formats.
    public function displayDate( $dateFormat )
    {
        list( $day, $month, $year ) = explode( '-', $this->dateString);

        switch($dateFormat)
        {

            case "YYYY-mm-dd" : $format = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day; break;
            case "mm-dd-YYYY" : $format = $month.'-'.$day.'-'.$year; break;
            default : $format = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;
        }
        return $format;
    }

    //Method to get day 
    public function day()
    {
        $day = date('d', strtotime($this->dateString));
        return $day;
    }

    //Method to get the day of the week.
    public function dayofweek()
    {
        $weekday = date('l', strtotime($this->dateString));
        return $weekday;

    }
    //Method to get month in text.
    public function getmonth()
    {
        $month = date('F', strtotime($this->dateString));
        return $month;
    }
} 


?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php 
//Initialisation
$date = new Date('14-01-2014');
$anotherdate = new Date('13-07-1979')

?>
    <h3>Instance 1</h3>
    <p>Date: <?php echo $date->displayDate('YYYY-mm-dd'); ?></p>
    <p>Day: <?php echo $date->day(); ?></p> 
    <p>Day of week: <?php echo $date->dayofweek(); ?></p>  
    <p>Month: <?php echo $date->getmonth(); ?></p> <br />
```

**Result:**
Instance 1
Date: 2014-01-14
Day: 14
Day of week: Tuesday
Month: January

I hope this could also help those who are just beginning to understand OOP.